# Android Development. Errors I can't handle with

Tags: java, android

I've just started android learning recently, and I'm trying to write one program, but always have different mistakes, so I've tried to rewrite it and get yet another mistake and the very beginning of it. I know that this question is "newby", but if you could help me it would be great. aso, here is the deal: it's kinda a game, and I create class extended from SurfaceView and which implements SurfaceHolder.Callback and a thread where could I do all the stuff, but though thread's start method do nothing, I catch an error.
Here is my project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22326796/Aquarium.7z
And here is some basic code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.skeeve.aquarium.AquariumView
        android:id="@+id/aquarium" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:background="@drawable/aquarium"/>
</FrameLayout>
public class AquariumView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private AquariumManager manager;

public AquariumView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    manager = new AquariumManager(surfaceHolder, context);      
}

public class AquariumActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

}

logfile: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22326796/log.txt

Comment: I don't know why you declare the surfaceview in your XML file instead of your Activity.

Comment: When i previously write this program I did that, but it didn't help much. Also, I checked LunarLander example project, and it uses pretty the same way as this.

Comment: I've just declared it in Activity, and by now it's seems to be ok, but I still don't understand why declaring it in XML is not working.

Comment: Because when you work on games, you generally want to do everything programmatically. You don't use XML layout except for menus. That's what they always told me when I was learning Android game dev.

Comment: It's strange, because such a way eliminates all the advantages of MVVM pattern.

Comment: MVVM isn't really use for game development ;) Plus, android is originally based on a MVC pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in your constructor (AquariumView.java)

change :

```
public AquariumView(Context context) {
     super(context);
```

by:

```
 public AquariumView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
```

Comment: thank you very much! such a silly mistake. it's the third time I'm rewriting this program, always overlook something...